# Breakpoint is not enabled for RIA Services Class Library

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have a RIA Services Class Library in my Silverlight OOB solution.  Breakpoints are not enabled in any code in this library when debugging the solution.  The module is not listed in the Debug/Modules window. Is it possible to debug your Class library services while running the Silverlight OOB solution?

Using:
Silverlight 5 Beta
VS 2010 10.0.40219.1
.NET Framework 4.0
C#

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked which Debuggers are enabled in the Project properties?

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is the main reason for Debugger not getting hit in RIA services.

Answer (score 0):

When I can't get in any other way, I insert this code:

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

in the service layer.  And you will be able to open that in a new instance of Visual Studio to step through.